# .find() top level <p> tags within div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <p> target </p>
  <p> target </p>
     <div>
       <p> not target </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I target all the top level `<p>` tags (see `target`) using `.find()`?

I can target **all** the `<p>` tags by:

```
jQuery(this).find("p"); // 'this' is .container
```

And I can target the *first* `<p>` tag by:

```
jQuery(this).find("p").first();
```

But I want to target both the top level `<p>` tags in `.container`.

Using CSS, I can do this by: `.container > p`

Comment: $(".container").find("> p");

Comment: @murli2308 I know that. I was asking how to do this via `.find()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use the CSS direct child selector:

```
jQuery(this).find("> p");
```

Or you can use `.children()`

```
jQuery(this).children("p");
```

Comment: Won't `.children()` included the lower level `p` tags in `.container`?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson No it won't.

Comment: "descendant selector" — That's the child combinator. The descendant combinator is a space. (And they aren't called selectors any more).

Comment: What's an indirect child? :)

Comment: @Quentin Grandchild.

Comment: That's a descendant that isn't a child. CSS doesn't use the term "direct" anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the direct descendant selector:

```
$(this).find("> p");
```

Comment: All descendants in DOM are direct, it doesn't have any concept of adoption or marriage. That is the child combinator not the direct descendant selector.

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery you would use the following selector

```
$(".container > p");
```

or

```
 $(".container").find("> p")[0];
```

for plain javascript you can do

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container > p');
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was asking how to do this via `.find()`